# Mean deviation in $p$-norm for $1 < p < 2$

Tags: reference-request, pr.probability, real-analysis

Let $(X, \mu)$ be a probability space, and let $p \in (1, 2)$ be arbitrary. It is known from Corollary 2.4 of this [paper](https://www.math.uwo.ca/faculty/sinnamon/pdf/holdmink.pdf) by G. Sinnamon that for any measurable $f : X \to [0, +\infty],$ we have

$$0 \leq \left( \int_X f^p \ d\mu\right) - \left(\int_X f \ d\mu\right)^p \leq \left\lVert f - \left(\int_X f \ d\mu\right) \right\rVert_p^p. \ \ \ (*)$$ (The first inequality is an immediate consequence of Jensen's inequality.)

I would like to know how "large" this inequality can be; in other words, how far is the reverse inequality from being true?

For example, does there exist some constant $C_p > 1$ such that for any $f$ as above and also with $\|f\|_p < +\infty,$ we have $$\left\lVert f - \left(\int_X f \ d\mu\right) \right\rVert_p^p \leq C_p \left[ \left( \int_X f^p \ d\mu\right) - \left(\int_X f \ d\mu\right)^p \right] \ ?$$

More generally, I am just wondering what can be said about the two sides of $(*)$ above in relation to one another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us rewrite the inequality in question as
$$E|f-1|^p\le C_p(Ef^p-1),$$
where $E$ is the expectation with respect to $\mu$ -- assuming, without loss of generality, that $Ef=1$.

This inequality does not hold in general for any $p\in(1,2)$ and any real constant $C_p$. Indeed, suppose e.g. that $f=1+tR$, where $P(R=1)=P(R=-1)=1/2$, $t>0$ is small, and $P:=\mu$. Then $Ef=1$,
$$E|f-1|^p=t^p,$$
and
$$Ef^p-1=\tfrac{1}{2} (1-t)^p+\tfrac{1}{2} (1+t)^p-1\sim (p-1)pt^2/2=o(t^p)=o(E|f-1|^p).$$

Comment: Thank you, Prof. Pinelis. If I may ask, where do you use the assumption $p<2$? 

Also, can you imagine any special cases in which the inequality involving $C_p$ might be true? I am interested in a rather specific class of functions $f$ that are measurable, in $L^p(X, \mu),$ take only nonnegative integer values, and are NOT in $L^2(X, \mu).$ Any further help would be much appreciated; thank you.

Comment: @MishelSkenderi : The assumption $p<2$ was used to get $o(t^p)$. The conditions that $f$ takes only nonnegative integer values and is not in $L^2(\mu$ will not help -- because any random variable (r.v) in $L^p$ can be however closely approximated in $L^p$ (and hence in $L^1$) by re-scaled r.v.'s not in $L^2$ that take only nonnegative integer values (and the inequality in question is invariant with respect to re-scaling). The example actually suggests that the inequality in question will not hold for any "reasonable" class of r.v.'s.

Comment: Thank you, Professor. However, I also want to mention that I am only interested in this inequality for $f$ as above and with the even further assumption that the expectation of $f$ ($L^1$ norm, since $f$ is nonnegative) is sufficiently large, so this makes me somewhat more hopeful because having sufficiently large $L^1$ norm seems to rule out the possibility of re-scaling. (Just to make things less cryptic: The class of $f$'s is a certain class of counting functions defined on a probability space and I am interested only in those functions whose count is, on average, large enough.)

Comment: @MishelSkenderi : The condition that $Ef$ is large (or small or whatever) is quite irrelevant too, as the re-scaling is always possible: the inequality in question holds if and only if it holds with $g:=f/Ef$ in place of $f$, whereas $Eg=1$. What makes the inequality in question false for any $C_p$ is that, in contrast with the right-hand side of the inequality, its left-hand side contains the absolute value sign and therefore can be much greater than the right-hand side. So, the inequality is quite hopeless.

Comment: @MishelSkenderi : I could give you a counterexample of a family $(f_n)$ of r.v.'s with values in the set of all nonnegative integers with $Ef_n\to\infty$ (as $n\to\infty$) and $Ef_n^2=\infty$ for all $n$ (so that all the conditions in your comments hold) such that the inequality in question is false for any real $C_p$ and all large enough $n$. However, I have to be sure that this would be the end of it (even though I am sure that, whatever new conditions you'd suggest, the inequality will not hold -- it cannot be saved).

Comment: No need; thank you!

Comment: By the way, I just want to mention that when $p \geq 2$, the reverse of the inequality in $(*)$ is actually true. (Of course, when $p = 2$, equality holds.) This is again Corollary 2.4 in the aforementioned paper. So I think the absolute value sign on one side is not the whole reason.

Comment: @MishelSkenderi : The case $p\ge2$ is quite different. If, as in the example, $f$ is close to its mean (say $1$), then $E(f^p-1)$ is on the order of $E(f-1)^2$, as the effects of the positive and negative deviations of $f$ from its mean get almost canceled out. Because of the absolute value sign, these effects of the positive and negative deviations of $f$ from its mean do not get canceled out.for  $E|f-1|^p$. Also, $E(f-1)^2$ is much less than $E|f-1|^p$ if $p<2$ and $E(f-1)^2$ is small; of course, it is vice versa for $p>2$.